# About Parse.com client side sharing app & api keys

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, client-side

I'm learning parse.com to implement small html5 clients. The cloud service provides out of the box methods to register users, create entries, etc.

Either I'm missing a thing or two (which I'm sure to be), either it's not unsafe to expose both app & api keys on the client side. I'm used to proxying calls to cloud service using a NodeJS relay that implements "max user operations /s" or "api abuses" like "prevent a user from calling 2000 times the "register user" function.

Is this sort of security implemented anywhere in parse.com services and I missed it... what would be your idea of a good usage of these api being open to public?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to assume that any user can get your application ID and client key. This is mentioned in the [Security](https://www.parse.com/docs/data#security) section of the parse documentation. You should be hiding your business logic inside cloud code, so you can implement the checks/security you need out of sight of the clients.

The other thing is that you cannot stop users hitting your API, once they know your application ID and client key. This **will** impact the API limits that parse have set. If you have a malicious user, they can "denial of service" your application and there is nothing you can do about it, apart from change your keys. Depending on how you have everything set up, this may impact clients.

A potential way around this is (as you've mentioned) putting a thin proxy inbetween the clients and parse. You can hide your application ID and client keys in the proxy, and implement some simple checks there to stop a denial of service.